# How to properly use filter method with foreign key in django details view with multiple models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have two model one model is being used for storing the blog posts and another model is being used for taking the ratings and  comments. Below are two my models

```
# Models Code
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='productImage')
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Snacks','Snacks'),
        ('Juice','Juice'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    review = models.TextField()

# Rating Model
class Rating(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stars = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(5)])
    comment = models.TextField()


#Views Code
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Products
    template_name = 'products.html'
    context_object_name ='Products'

class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Products

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Rating'] = Rating.objects.filter(self.product_id) # How can i get the comments only for that specific product?
        return context
```

In details-view how should I filter to fetch the comments for that specific product only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to write separate context for that in `ProductDetailView`, you can do it as follows in templates

```
{% for rate in object.rating_set.all %}
 {{ rate.comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank You, It worked, but can you please tell me how did it work as I don't have any rating_set attribute in my Product table?

Comment: that is the reverse lookup for the FK, child model name in small letter _set, if you have a related name then you can call that name directly without _set